# mounting 500k files in google drive on colab wont work

Tags: google-colaboratory, drive

)

Unfortunately i created lots of files over colab in my google drive. Now it seems its impossible to mount it on colab anymore.

I guess the process gets killed because of a timeout.
Any suggestions?

Thx

```
    TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x7ff3dbe17390>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile('google.colab.drive MOUNTED')
    1: re.compile('root@e84b0df49b86-09bc9916abe94fe5875728ad91a75e71: ')
    2: re.compile('(Go to this URL in a browser: https://.*)$')
    3: re.compile('Drive File Stream encountered a problem and has stopped')
    4: re.compile('drive EXITED')
    5: re.compile('Authorization failed')
    6: re.compile('The domain policy has disabled Drive File Stream')
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x7ff3dbe17390>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile('google.colab.drive MOUNTED')
    1: re.compile('root@e84b0df49b86-09bc9916abe94fe5875728ad91a75e71: ')
    2: re.compile('(Go to this URL in a browser: https://.*)$')
    3: re.compile('Drive File Stream encountered a problem and has stopped')
    4: re.compile('drive EXITED')
    5: re.compile('Authorization failed')
    6: re.compile('The domain policy has disabled Drive File Stream')
```

Comment: To check I'm understanding correctly. You're creating lots of files in Colab and you want them to appear in a Google Drive folder that you have mounted into the Colab notebook. If that's true, you could zip the files and then copy this zip file to Google Drive.

Comment: hey i created them with colab while it was mounted. and now im not able to connect and i have no way to access that many files over the web interface ;D

Comment: So you created lots of files in your Google Drive and now Google Drive doesn't work?

Comment: google drive does work but im not able to mount it any more on colab

Comment: Delete the files and start again. Create all the files you want inside Colab. then zip them and copy this to Google Drive